# Create layout custom title

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I want to create an android interface, something like a launcher. For this, I need to make a custom title bar and 2 borders in each side of the screen.

I have several activities in my app, and I need this to be in all of them, so I need to create independent layouts, one with the custom titlebar and another with the borders. The result may be this:

[image: draw]

This is the xml for the borders:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout   
    android:id="@+id/border_left"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#000000" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/border_right"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#000000" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the xml for the tittle:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#000000" >
```

The questions are 2:

- How can I put in the middle of the titlebar (the red square) a logo (image)?
- How can I insert these 2 layouts into the other activities? For example, how could I make my plain main layout include these 2 layouts?

Comment: use sherlock action bar library to create custom title bar

Comment: Well, is not an action bar what I need, but a custom title, but I'll have a look on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the second question: include the layout into another layout:

```
<include
    layout = "@layout/custom_tittlebar" >
</include>
```

I'm still fighting with the titlebar, I want to put the image that way and I'm thinking if this is the best way, or maybe I have to create an image with photoshop setting the logo on it, and then set it as background in the layout.